# Помогите найти ошибку! В последней строчке кода ошибка "Unresolved reference 'numbers' ". Что я сделал не так?

Tags: python

Написать функцию которая принимает список чисел и возвращает наибольшее из чисел, встроенные функции использовать нельзя

```
import random

def get_max(numbers):
    numbers = []
    counter = 0
    max_number = -9999999999999999999
    while counter < counter_max:
        numbers.append(random.randint(1, 100))
        counter += 1
    print(numbers)
    for number in numbers:
        if number > max_number:
            number = max_number
            print(max_number)
            return max_number


counter_max = int(input('Введите желаемое количество чисел в списке: '))
get_max(numbers)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: При проверки работы кода, выдается ошибка : 
NameError: name 'numbers' is not defined

Comment: И это правильно, чему равна переменная numbers?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь передать в функцию в качестве аргумента локальную переменную, объявленную в теле данной функции (то бишь доступа из глобала Вы к ней не имеете). Не совсем понял, какую задачу должен решать написанный Вами код, распишите подробнее свою цель.

Comment: `Написать функцию которая принимает список чисел`, но передаете вы в функцию не список

Comment: Мне нужно решить задачу ( изучаю пайтон). Нужно написать функцию, которая принимает список чисел и возвращает наибольшее из чисел, встроенные функции использовать нельзя

Comment: Удалил аргумент и все получилось. Я пока не до конца понял, буду разбираться! Спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import random

def get_max():
    numbers = []
    counter = 0
    max_number = -9999999999999999999
    while counter < counter_max:
        numbers.append(random.randint(1, 100))
        counter += 1
    print(numbers)
    for number in numbers:
        if number > max_number:
            max_number = number
    print(f'Максимальное число в списке:  {max_number}')
    return max_number


counter_max = int(input('Введите желаемое количество чисел в списке: '))
get_max()
```

Comment: `Написать функцию которая принимает список чисел` - get_max() ничего не принимает, а должна принимать список.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Answer (score 1):

Код у вас сильно не правильный. Я его сильно переделал:

```py
import random


def get_max(counter_max):  # <-- Здесь надо принимать не `numbers` а `counter_max`.
    numbers = []
    for counter in range(counter_max):  # (1
        numbers.append(random.randint(1, 100))
        counter += 1                    # 1)

    max_number = numbers[0]
    for number in numbers:       # (2
        if number > max_number:
            number = max_number  # 2)

    return max_number


counter_max = int(input('Введите желаемое количество чисел в списке: '))
print(get_max(counter_max))  # <-- Здесь надо передавать не `numbers` а `counter_max`.
```

Но чтобы решить задачу: "Написать функцию которая принимает список чисел и возвращает наибольшее из чисел, встроенные функции использовать нельзя", то так:

```py
def get_max(numbers):
    max_number = numbers[0]
    for number in numbers:
        if number > max_number:
            max_number = number

    return max_number


print(get_max(list(map(int, input().split()))))
```

Ввод:

```
1 2 3 4 5 66
```

Вывод:

```
66
```

Comment: Спасибо, что помогаете разобраться. 
Я хотел, чтобы список генерировался случайным образом

Comment: @AndreiTaras Пожалуйста.